# How to perform substitutions on the TAST using the Scala 3 reflection API and account for shadowing?

Tags: scala, reflection, metaprogramming, scala-3

I am working with the Scala 3 reflection API to perform substitutions on the TAST (Typed Abstract Syntax Trees). I have written a method that traverses the TAST and replaces occurrences of a specific identifier with a replacement expression from a substitution map that is given at runtime. The implementation is as follows:

```scala
inline def rewriteProgram(inline expr: (Int, Int, Int) => Int): Map[String, Int] => Int =
  ${ generateClosure('expr) }


private def generateClosure(expr: Expr[(Int, Int, Int) => Int])(using
    quotes: Quotes
): Expr[Map[String, Int] => Int] =
  import quotes.reflect.*
  val tree = expr.asTerm
  tree match
    case Inlined(_, _, Block(_, block)) =>
      block match
        case Block(stmts, _) =>
          stmts.head match
            case DefDef(_, List(TermParamClause(funParams)), _, Some(body)) =>
              val rewrittenBody = rewriteBody(funParams, body)(Symbol.spliceOwner)
              rewrittenBody.asExprOf[Map[String, Int] => Int]
            ... // Removed for brevity

private def rewriteBody(using quotes: Quotes)(
    funParams: List[quotes.reflect.ValDef],
    body: quotes.reflect.Term
)(sym: quotes.reflect.Symbol): quotes.reflect.Term =
  import quotes.reflect.*
  // Map[String, Int] => Int
  Lambda(
    owner = Symbol.spliceOwner,
    tpe = MethodType(List("_"))(
      _ =>
        List(
          TypeRepr.of[Map[String, Int]]
        ),
      _ => TypeRepr.of[Int]
    ),
    rhsFn = (sym: Symbol, params: List[Tree]) =>
      val env        = params.head.asInstanceOf[Ident]
      val boundNames = funParams.map(_.name)

      val transform = new TreeMap:
        override def transformTerm(tree: Term)(owner: Symbol): Term =
          tree match
            case Ident(name) =>
              substitute(name, env, tree)(owner)
            case _ =>
              super.transformTerm(tree)(owner)

      transform.transformTerm(body)(sym)
  )

private def substitute(using
    quotes: Quotes
)(n: String, env: quotes.reflect.Term, term: quotes.reflect.Term)(
    sym: quotes.reflect.Symbol
): quotes.reflect.Term =
  import quotes.reflect.*

  val transform = new TreeMap:
    override def transformTerm(tree: Term)(owner: Symbol): Term =
      tree match
        case Ident(name) if name equals n =>
          val v = '{ (${ env.asExprOf[Map[String, Int]] })(${ Expr(name) }) }.asTerm
          v.changeOwner(owner)
        case _ =>
          super.transformTerm(tree)(owner)
    
    // Failed attempt at only replacing the RHS side of vals
    // override def transformStatement(tree: Statement)(owner: Symbol): Statement =
    //  tree match
    //    case ValDef(name, tpt, Some(rhs)) if name equals n =>
    //      val newRHS = substitute(n, env, rhs)(owner)
    //      ValDef.copy(tree)(name, tpt, Some(newRHS)).changeOwner(owner)
    //    case _ =>
    //      super.transformStatement(tree)(owner)

  transform.transformTerm(term)(sym)
```

In the `rewriteBody` method, I traverse the TAST and replace occurrences of identifiers with a replacement expression. The `substitute` method is used to perform the actual substitution. The `rewriteBody` method returns a `(Map[String, Int] => Int` closure. It is intended to be used as follows:

```scala
  val substs: Map[String, Int] =
    Map("x" -> 1, "y" -> 2, "z" -> 3, "a" -> 4, "b" -> 5, "c" -> 6)

  def prog : Map[String, Int] => Int = 
    rewriteProgram { (x: Int, w: Int, z: Int) =>
      x match
        case y =>
          val y : Int = x + y
          x + y
    }
  
  prog(substs)
```

However, I am unsure how to handle shadowing of variables. For example, if there is a local variable in the body of the function that has the same name as one of the function parameters, the local variable should shadow the function parameter. Or any occurrence of the identifier the tree should stop the substitution operation for that identifier in the rest of the program.

One failed attempt was that I tried to traverse the given TAST and find any occurrence of a `ValDef(name, ...)` where `name` is the same as the variable I'm attempting to replace and perform the substitution only on the RHS of the `val` if it is defined and copy return a copy of it. The attempted code is as follows and should be placed within the `transform` in the `substitute` function:

```scala
    override def transformStatement(tree: Statement)(owner: Symbol): Statement =
      tree match
        case ValDef(name, tpt, Some(rhs)) if name equals n =>
          val newRHS = substitute(n, env, rhs)(owner)
          ValDef.copy(tree)(name, tpt, Some(newRHS)).changeOwner(owner)
        case _ =>
          super.transformStatement(tree)(owner)
```

I would greatly appreciate any help or guidance on how to approach this problem. Thank you.

Comment: OTOH, instead of using `name` - either extracted with unapply or through `.name` method - you can obtain `.symbol` from `Tree` and (if != `Symbol.noSymbol`) use it instead of name, as `Symbol`s can have the same name but their equality check does not look only at their name. So overshadowed variables with the same `.name` would have different `.symbol`s which makes them more reliable for such comparison.